# String format currency with alignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print('this is £{0:>10.2f}'.format(3.44))
```

prints out:

```
this is £      3.44
```

i.e. separates the `£` from the amount. Is there any way to print printing spaced columns with a currency sign in the right place, next to the amount? E.g.

```
this is      £3.44
```

I tried `print('this is {0:£>10.2f}'.format(3.44))` but get:

```
this is ££££££3.44
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to do this in two steps, one for the currency symbol and decimal places and another for the right-align with spaces:

```
>>> 'this is {:>10}'.format('£{:.2f}'.format(3.44))
'this is      £3.44'
```

If you want comma-separated thousands, you can also include a `,` in the format specification:

```
>>> 'this is {:>10}'.format('£{:,.2f}'.format(1003.44))
'this is  £1,003.44'
```

Comment: Thank you Jon - that does it!

Comment: @MarkThomas no problem! FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

You used right align with {:>10}, if you want left align, try this:

```
In[21]: print('this is £{0:<10.2f}'.format(3.44))
this is £3.44
```