# Python using string in '%x.xf' % formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am working on a program, and I have written out a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. I want to line up dollar signs on the left hand side, while still keeping the decimals lined up on the right. Here is my code so far-

```
money = float(input("Enter  amount: "))
random = float(input("Enter a random number"))
print()

print("Random number: ", '%12.0f' % random) #I just want this to line up
print("Money each month: ", '%12.2f' % ((money) / 12.0))
print("Total money: ", '%17.2f' % money)`
```

The output lines up so that the decimals are all in a row, and the random number is right before a decimal. The problem is, when I try to add a dollar sign to the `equation( '%12.2f' % "$", )` it says it isn't compatible because the formatting doesn't work with strings.. Is there a different format option I should use, or is there a different way to arrange it? Any help would be appreciated. I just created an account here today and I've only been programming for about a few weeks so sorry if this is poorly written.

Comment: So you want to print something like $12.00?

Comment: Please add sample output.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to improve this:

1. The string formatting methods don't require the formatting string to be separated from the surrounding text. The "right" way to use them is to embed the formatting codes into a longer string, then attach the values at the end.
2. You are using the older "printf" style formatting, but it is considered [preferable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) to use the newer `str.format()` method for new code.
3. If you want to place the currency symbol close to your number, but also pad to the left of that up to a certain width, you will need to do it in two steps (first format the number with the currency symbol, then pad to the left), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42658877/3830997).

With that in mind, here's some code that should do the job:

```
money = 12323.45
random = 2278

# format with decimals and dollar sign (variable width)
money_formatted = '${:.2f}'.format(money)
monthly_money_formatted = '${:.2f}'.format(money/12.0)

print()
print("Random number:    {:9.0f}".format(random))
# pad to 12 characters if needed
print("Money each month: {:>12}".format(monthly_money_formatted))
print("Total money:      {:>12}".format(money_formatted))

# output:
# Random number:         2278
# Money each month:     $1026.95
# Total money:         $12323.45
```

Comment: 2.: the source doesn’t really state that the newer method is “preferable”. It says 

“Each of these alternatives provides their own trade-offs and benefits of simplicity, flexibility, and/or extensibility.”

Answer (score 0):

This

```
money = float(input("Enter  amount: "))
random = float(input("Enter a random number"))
print()

randomFormatted = f"{random:.0f}"
money12Formatted = f"{(money/12.0):.2f}"
moneyFormatted = f"{money:.2f}"
print(f"Random number:{' ':3}{randomFormatted.rjust(6)}")
print(f"Money each month:{' ':2}${money12Formatted.rjust(6)}")
print(f"Total money:{' ':7}${moneyFormatted.rjust(6)}")
```

Gives output:

```
Random number:       32
Money each month:  $  4.17
Total money:       $ 50.00
```

I don't know how to nest the number formatting into the same statement as the string padding, though.